# Admin area can't load any assets

Tags: assets, admin

I just uploaded my website on my server and I have a problem regarding the admin area. When I arrive on the /admin page, no CSS and no JS have been loaded (after inspection, they all 404'd).

Is there any way to fix this like in the general config ? Thanks a lot !

EDIT :

The .htaccess is working (404 act differently).

Comment: Are you running Apache/nginx? Have you renamed the `htaccess` file to `.htaccess`?

Comment: yup, and I renamed it. The point is that my website is working, but the dashboard isnt

Comment: So it's Apache?

Comment: Edit : If It can help, the problem seems to be in the dynamic routes loading the assets. I believe there's some parameters to override in general config but none of them worked for now.

Comment: Take a peek at apache's access/error logs after you hit the dashboard, there might be some clues in there to help lead  you to what's going on. A missing image could actually masquerade as a 403 for example...