# Hardcoding admin assets urls

Tags: assets, admin

I moved my website from my local dev environment to my production server, but my admin assets are not resolving. I tried everything but didn't work. In fact it's probably a problem on the server side, but I cant do anything about it.

Now, is there a way to hardcode those assets in the admin pages ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should be able to get it working without hardcoding anything. I see you still have [your other question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/admin-area-cant-load-any-assets) open, probably related?

Comment: Yes but now I can say that the problem is from apache, but I can't fix it because I'm on a free hosting solution. So I thought about hardcoding assets url , this way I'm sure It will work

Comment: Even the cheapest hosts I've worked with supported some flavor of .htaccess which I think is your issue. But without any more information, for example an error log, it's hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I ran a couple of tests and found some strange stuff. The phpinfo doesn't give any informations about the server but a ctrl-f gave me one occurrence of apache (but no nginx). But the server 404 clearly shows that it runs under nginx. Another strange thing is that the root .htaccess changes the behaviour of the system if I modify it . I don't have any access to the logs either. The problem concerns css and js assets, which I load like "siteUrl ~ 'css/stuff.css'. Same goes for js. I tried to modify the url of assets in CP , and noticed that the craft/ .htaccess is not working. Thanks !

Comment: OK so i'm confused. When you mean admin, do you mean the Craft dashboard where you log in and change content? 

The reason I'm asking is you are now mentioning twig templates, which are a completely different front end problem. It sounds like you need to put your site assets in the proper document root.  If you have your ``css`` folder inside your craft/templates folder, for example, that's not going to resolve when you visit the site.

Comment: The problem is only with the craft admin part (login parts and the rest, I cant even login). My assets are not in craft folder, I put them in /web